# bamboo failure on gcloud ERROR: gcloud crashed (UnicodeDecodeError): 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 1438: ordinal not in range 128

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bitbucket, gcloud, bamboo

Bitbucket pipeline was working fine to deploy application to GCP app engine. Suddenly getting error while connecting to gcloud.

This application is based on microservices, It build and deploy the services one by one using maven

mvn gcloud deploy

```
build   29-Jun-2023 13:12:41    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.google.appengine:gcloud-maven-plugin:2.0.9.133.v201611104:deploy (default-cli) on project egsp-sga-admin: Error: gcloud app command exit code is: 1
build   29-Jun-2023 13:12:41        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
build   29-Jun-2023 13:12:41        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
build   29-Jun-2023 13:12:41        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
build   29-Jun-2023 13:12:41        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
build   29-Jun-2023 13:12:41        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
build   29-Jun-2023 13:12:41        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
build   29-Jun-2023 13:12:41        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
build   29-Jun-2023 13:12:41        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
```

POM.XML

```
   <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>gcloud-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.9.133.v201611104</version>
                <configuration>
                    <gcloud_directory>/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/</gcloud_directory>
                    <verbosity>info</verbosity>
                    <promote>true</promote>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gae.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
                    <version>${app.version}</version>
                    <address>0.0.0.0</address>
                    <jvmFlags>
                        <jvmFlag>-Xdebug</jvmFlag>
                        <jvmFlag>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n</jvmFlag>
                    </jvmFlags>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

checked with bamboo team, they have installed python 3.9 version on server keeping 2.7 intact.pipeline was working post this for 1 week, post that its failing on cloud deploy.

Need help, I have referred all the available issues on stackoverflow but none seem relevant to this.

No changes on code level. No path or modifications done.

Tried deploying the old successful build from bamboo but it is failing with same error.

Getting this issue in DEV, SIT and UAT environments.

SDK and Python versions installed on Bamboo:

```
[root@bambooagent-4 ~]# gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 287.0.0
alpha 2020.03.30
app-engine-java 1.9.79
app-engine-python 1.9.89
beta 2020.03.30
bq 2.0.56
cloud-datastore-emulator 2.1.0
core 2020.03.30
gsutil 4.49
kubectl 2020.03.30
[root@bambooagent-4 ~]# gcloud info --run-diagnostics
Network diagnostic detects and fixes local network connection issues.
Checking network connection...done.                                                                                                   
Reachability Check passed.
Network diagnostic passed (1/1 checks passed).

Property diagnostic detects issues that may be caused by properties.
Checking hidden properties...done.                                                                                                    
Hidden Property Check passed.
Property diagnostic passed (1/1 checks passed).




[root@bambooagent-4 ~]# gcloud info
Google Cloud SDK [287.0.0]

Platform: [Linux, x86_64] ('Linux', 'bambooagent-4', '3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64', '#1 SMP Mon Dec 2 08:31:54 EST 2019', 'x86_64', 'x86
_64')
Locale: ('en_GB', 'UTF-8')
Python Version: [2.7.5 (default, Jun 11 2019, 14:33:56)  [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]]
Python Location: [/bin/python2]
Site Packages: [Disabled]

Installation Root: [/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk]
Installed Components:
  core: [2020.03.30]
  app-engine-python: [1.9.89]
  kubectl: [2020.03.30]
  app-engine-java: [1.9.79]
  beta: [2020.03.30]
  gsutil: [4.49]
  bq: [2.0.56]
  alpha: [2020.03.30]
  cloud-datastore-emulator: [2.1.0]
System PATH: [/usr/local/rbenv/shims:/usr/local/rbenv/bin:/opt/gradle/gradle-7.2/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin]
Python PATH: [/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party:/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/lib:/usr/lib64/python27.zip:/usr/lib64/python2.7/
:/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2:/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk:/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old:/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload]
Cloud SDK on PATH: [False]
Kubectl on PATH: [/bin/kubectl]

Installation Properties: [/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/properties]
User Config Directory: [/root/.config/gcloud]
Active Configuration Name: [default]
Active Configuration Path: [/root/.config/gcloud/configurations/config_default]
```